# Python commandline argument that can be either Empty or from a Choice list

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I am working on a script for controlling builds of Docker images.
I currently support one or more base images of Centos and one or more of Debian.
I would like "--centos" or "--debian" to default to the latest version.
But if the user wants to build an older copy, then this should come from a choice list.
Thus, I am looking for a hybrid of:
    parser.add_argument('--centos',  choices=['centos-6','centos-7'])
and
    parser.add_argument('--centos')

so I could run the script like:

`python dobuild.py --centos            #would build the latest centos in the list`

or

`python dobuild.py --centos centos-6   #would build the older copy`

but

`python dobuild.py --centos centos-5   #would return an 'invalid choice' error`

I tried `choices=['centos-6','centos-7','']` and `choices=['centos-6','centos-7', []]`

for completeness:  `python dobuild.py --centos --debian  #would build the latest centos AND latest debian in the list`
etc . . .

Comment: I don't know of any batteries-included way to have this exact syntax, but it's kind of not great, right? Why not a series of flags `--centos`, `--centos-6`, `--centos-7`, etc that are allowed?

Comment: Not a bad thought @AdamSmith
would require a bit more verbosity than the  current method as the 'valid' list comes from a dictionary structure called IMAGES:

```parser.add_argument('--centos',  choices=list(IMAGES['centos'].keys()),  help=f"""Image for compiling on Centos Linux  (default={list(IMAGES['centos'])[0]})""", required=required)```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add this optional argument with a default you can use `nargs='?'` and `const='<default>'`. [Here in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs)

> Note that for optional arguments, there is an additional case - the option string is present but not followed by a command-line argument. In this case the value from const will be produced:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--centos', choices=['centos-6', 'centos-7'], nargs='?', const='centos-7')
```

Using this parser:

```
>>> parser.parse_args([])
Namespace(centos=None)
>>> parser.parse_args(['--centos'])
Namespace(centos='centos-7')
>>> parser.parse_args(['--centos', 'centos-6'])
Namespace(centos='centos-6')
```

Comment: Wow @Iain Shelvington
Thank you for the great answer and with actual code.   Very helpful.